# Connection Timed Out - Apache2 & Django Deployment

Tags: python, django, webserver, apache2, apache2.4

I rent a Ubuntu VPS and deployed my Django project using Apache2. But when I try to connect port 80(HTTP) with the IP number it results in the connection timed out. Here is my Apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/SistemDedektifi/SistemDedektifi/SistemDedektifi/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess SistemDedektifi python-home=/var/www/html/SistemDedektifi/SistekDedektifi/venv python-path=/var/www/html/SistemDedektifi/SistemDedektifi
WSGIProcessGroup SistemDedektifi


Alias /static /var/www/html/SistemDedektifi/SistemDedektifi/static
<Directory /var/www/html/SistemDedektifi/SistemDedektifi/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>


<Directory /var/www/html/SistemDedektifi/SistemDedektifi/SistemDedektifi>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Last two days I am working on configuring this but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Is the IP address in Django settings `allowed hosts`?

Comment: yes it's in there

Comment: are there any error logs from apache or django? It probably not even making it to django.. if it was, you could check your gunicorn(?) logs. Does this help w/ apache? https://blog.codeasite.com/how-do-i-find-apache-http-server-log-files/